# How do we precompile base templates in Cheetah so that #include, #extends and #import works properly in Weby

Tags: python, inheritance, web.py

How do you serve **Cheetah** in **production**?

Guys can you share the setup on how to precompile and serve cheetah in production

Since we dont compile templates in webpy it is getting upstream time out errors. If you could share a good best practise it would help

*

> Jeremy wrote:
>   For a production site, I use Cheetah
>   with pre-compiled templates - it's
>   very fast (the templates import
>   especially quickly when python
>   compiled and optimised). A bit of
>   magic with the imp module takes a
>   template name and a base directory
>   (configured in a site-specific config)
>   and loads up that template, taking
>   care of #extends and
>
> ## import directives as appropriate. I don't use the built-in support for
>
> Cheetah, however. The new template
>   library is also only imported to
>   display the debugerror page

*

Answer (score 1):

Maybe compile automagically on as needed basis:

```
import sys
import os
from os import path
import logging
from Cheetah.Template import Template
from Cheetah.Compiler import Compiler

log = logging.getLogger(__name__)

_import_save = __import__
def cheetah_import(name, *args, **kw):
  """Import function which search for Cheetah templates.

  When template ``*.tmpl`` is found in ``sys.path`` matching module
  name (and corresponding generated Python module is outdated or
  not existent) it will be compiled prior to actual import.
  """
  name_parts = name.split('.')
  for p in sys.path:
    basename = path.join(p, *name_parts)
    tmpl_path = basename+'.tmpl'
    py_path = basename+'.py'
    if path.exists(tmpl_path):
      log.debug("%s found in %r", name, tmpl_path)
      if not path.exists(py_path) or newer(tmpl_path, py_path):
        log.info("cheetah compile %r -> %r", tmpl_path, py_path)
        output = Compiler(
            file=tmpl_path,
            moduleName=name,
            mainClassName=name_parts[-1],
            )
        open(py_path, 'wb').write(str(output))
      break
  return _import_save(name, *args, **kw)

def newer(new, old):
    """Whether file with path ``new`` is newer then at ``old``."""
    return os.stat(new).st_mtime > os.stat(old).st_mtime

import __builtin__
__builtin__.__import__ = cheetah_import
```

Answer (score 0):

**This works**

```
try:web.render('mafbase.tmpl', None, True, 'mafbase')
except:pass
```

**This is what i did with you code**

```
from cheetahimport import *
sys.path.append('./templates')
cheetah_import('mafbase')
```

## includes dont work in the given method.

**This is the error i got**

```
    localhost pop]$ vi code.py
    [mark@localhost pop]$ ./code.py 9911
    http://0.0.0.0:9911/
    Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "/home/mark/work/common/web/application.py", line 241, in process
     return self.handle()
    File "/home/mark/work/common/web/application.py", line 232, in handle
    return self._delegate(fn, self.fvars, args)
    File "/home/mark/work/common/web/application.py", line 411, in _delegate
    return handle_class(cls)
    File "/home/mark/work/common/web/application.py", line 386, in handle_class
    return tocall(*args)
    File "user.py", line 264, in proxyfunc
    return func(self, *args, **kw)
    File "/home/mark/work/pop/code.py", line 1801, in GET
    return web.render('subclass.html')
    File "/home/mark/work/common/web/cheetah.py", line 104, in render
    return str(compiled_tmpl)
    File "/usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/Cheetah-2.0.1-py2.5-linux-i686.egg/Cheetah/Template.py", line 982, in __str__
    def __str__(self): return getattr(self, mainMethName)()
    File "templates/mafbase.py", line 713, in respond
    self._handleCheetahInclude("widgetbox.html", trans=trans, includeFrom="file", raw=False)
    File "/usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/Cheetah-2.0.1-py2.5-linux-i686.egg/Cheetah/Template.py", line 1512, in _handleCheetahInclude
    nestedTemplateClass = compiler.compile(source=source,file=file)
    File "/usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/Cheetah-2.0.1-py2.5-linux-i686.egg/Cheetah/Template.py", line 693, in compile
     fileHash = str(hash(file))+str(os.path.getmtime(file))
   File "/usr/lib/python2.5/posixpath.py", line 143, in getmtime
    return os.stat(filename).st_mtime
   OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/mark/work/pop/widgetbox.html'
```